# Renewcommand inside another environment

Tags: macros, environments, tcolorbox

I create an environment with three commands in the end. They are not compiled when putting after end of tcolorbox.
Please explain why the below code is wrong? How does correct them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand{\dapso}[1]{\renewcommand{\dapsoend}{\par #1}}
\newcommand{\dongke}[1]{\renewcommand{\dongkeend}
    {\multido{}{#1}{\newline.\dotfill}}}
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{\renewcommand{\loigiaiend}{\par #1}}
\newcommand{\loigiaiend}{}
\newcommand{\dapsoend}{}
\newcommand{\dongkeend}{}
\newcounter{ex}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{ext}{{\refstepcounter{ex}\bfseries Ex \theex}}{\dapsoend\dongkeend\loigiaiend}
\newenvironment{ex}{\begin{tcolorbox}{\refstepcounter{ex}\bfseries Ex \theex}}
    {\end{tcolorbox}\dapsoend\dongkeend\loigiaiend}
\begin{document}
\begin{ext}
    Contents
    \loigiai{Solution \theex}
    \dapso{Answer \theex}
    \dongke{4}
\end{ext}

\begin{ex}
    Contents
    \loigiai{Solution \theex}
    \dapso{Answer \theex}
    \dongke{4}
\end{ex}

\textbf{\large\color{blue}Hope  below results}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{Ex \theex} Contents
\end{tcolorbox}
\par Solution \theex
\par Answer \theex
\multido{}{4}{\newline.\dotfill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is solved when \renewcommand is replaced by \gdef. I don't know why it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the effects of `\renewcommand` (and `\newcommand`) are local and `\begin`…`\end` creates a group so the `\renewcommand` will no longer be in effect when the group ends. There are two possible solutions.

1. Drop down to TeX primitives and write instead, e.g.,¹

   ```
   \NewDocumentCommand{\loigiai}{m}{\gdef\loigiaiend{\par #1\gdef\loigiaiend{}}}
   ```

   note that I added a second redefinition of the `end` command inside its definition so that you won't have the value carry over to other environments where you didn't specify `\loigiai`.²
2. The other idea would be to move the calls to `\loigiai` et al. from the body of the environment to an argument on the environment itself. Your definition would change to

   ```
   \NewDocumentEnvironment{ext}{ m }
       {#1\begin{tcolorbox}{\refstepcounter{ex}\bfseries Ex \theex}}
       {\end{tcolorbox}\dapsoend\dongkeend\loigiaiend}
   ```

   and then you would call it with

   ```
   \begin{ext}{%
       \loigiai{Solution \theex}
       \dapso{Answer \theex}
       \dongke{4}
      }
       Contents
   \end{ext}
   ```

   Incidentally, `\NewDocumentEnvironment` has the advantage that you can easily change that to an optional argument by changing the `{ m }` in the definition to `{ O{} }`.

   It might also make sense to consider having three arguments to the environment and having the environment do the calls to `\loigiai` et al itself:

   ```
   \NewDocumentEnvironment{ext}{ mmm }
       {
         \loigiai{#1}
         \dapso{#2}
         \dongke{#3}
         \begin{tcolorbox}{\refstepcounter{ex}\bfseries Ex \theex}}
       {\end{tcolorbox}\dapsoend\dongkeend\loigiaiend}
   ```

   although seeing things like `\theex` in the arguments to `\loigiai` makes me wonder whether your current approach might not be able to made simpler still.

---

1. Continuing my efforts to drive `\newcommand` to extinction.
2. You should probably also replace your initializations of the `end` commands with e.g. `\gdef\loigiaiend{}` as well. If you mix global and local assignments for the same value in LaTeX there is a (documented) memory leak that take place, although in this instance, it's not dramatic.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! It is very clearly.